# How to access values inside validationSchema in formik

Tags: formik

values are accessible only if I use validation but not inside validationschema

```
<Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema(values)}
        onSubmit={actions.handleSubmit}
      >
        <Form>
```

if I use useFormikContext(); values are not accessible inside validationSchema because initialization happens after Formik.

how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5):

**Use validate instead of validationSchema**

Pass your Form data as **4th argument** in validateYupSchema which represents context and can be accessed later in schema.

Pass your schema as **2nd argument** in validateYupSchema.

```
<Formik
      validate={(values) => {
        try {
          validateYupSchema(values, validationSchema, true, values);
        } catch (err) {
          return yupToFormErrors(err); //for rendering validation errors
        }

        return {};
      }}

       onSubmit={} />
```

Now we can access any form value using `this.options.context` inside test function in schema

Comment: @naveen kumar pg this is the answer. Give him the check!

Answer (score 0):

- If you need to validate one formik value *conditionally* based on another formik values,
  you can achieve using **when()** method chaining inside of validationSchema like so:

```js
   const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    is_female: Yup.boolean('Select The Pricing'),
    female_price: Yup.string().when('is_female', {
      is: isFemale => isFemale === true,
      then: Yup.string().required('Female Price is required')
    }),
    male_price: Yup.string().when('is_female', {
      is: isFemale => isFemale === false,
      then: Yup.string().required('Male Price is required')
    })
   });

   <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={actions.handleSubmit}
      />
```

- Hope this helps.